# Bamboo ProcessService bean does not exist?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, bamboo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Following https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/bamboo-tasks-api/executing-external-processes-using-processservice I would like to invoke some command using ProcessService bean. The injection as described in the link, does not work. 
I checked the source of several other plugins at Bitbucket, but each is using the concept as described in the link.

My class:

```
import com.atlassian.bamboo.process.ProcessService;

public class CheckTask implements TaskType {
    private final ProcessService processService;
    public CheckTask(@NotNull final ProcessService processService) {
        this.processService = processService;
    }
```

However Bamboo does not find the ProcessService bean and fail with following:

> (org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException :
>   Error creating bean with name 'bamboo.tasks.CheckTask': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
>   [com.atlassian.bamboo.process.ProcessService]: : No qualifying bean of
>   type [com.atlassian.bamboo.process.ProcessService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.atlassian.bamboo.process.ProcessService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {})

Am I missing something ?
Bamboo version: 5.13.0
AMPS version:    6.2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in the end was quite simple, no oficial docs discuss the solution though. Hope this helps you a bit.

Finally thanks to this post I made it work: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/33141765/testcollationservice-not-injected-into-tasktype-constructor-on-sdk-bamboo

```
import com.atlassian.bamboo.process.ProcessService;
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.component.Scanned;
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.ComponentImport;

@Scanned
public class CheckTask implements TaskType {

    @ComponentImport
    private final ProcessService processService;

    public CheckTask(@NotNull final ProcessService processService) {
        this.processService = processService;
    }
```

The rest of the project was basicaly default, as generated by atlas-create-bamboo-plugin.

Comment: Note that the @Autowired is left out intentionally. No need for that. Just to justify my comment under the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in your *atlassian-plugin.xml* next line

```
<component-import key="processService" 
        interface="com.atlassian.bamboo.process.ProcessService"/>
```

That should help you

Comment: Thanks for your help. The plugin build now unfortunately fails with: atlassian-plugin.xml contains a definition of component-import. This is not allowed when Atlassian-Plugin-Key is set. 

The Atlassian-Plugin-Key part was generated by the atlas-create-bamboo-plugin.

Comment: Atlassian has updated recently way how components should be imported. So, component-impot is an old way, but there is new way via spring scanner (http://www.j-tricks.com/tutorials/atlassian-spring-scanner-and-nosuchbeandefinitionexception) which is unfortunetly doesn't work well.

Try to find something in your pom.xml about Atlassian-Plugin-Key and remove it or follow documentation on link about new way of component-import

Comment: Thanks, there are also 2 links following the error. I am just reading through. Will get back if I figure out something.

Comment: Your link pointed me to a several different articles and how-tos, but still not working. Which leads me back to my orginal solution and problem. This is all interesting but with one presumption to be true. That the atlas-create-bamboo-plugin template is wrong (or not up to date or whatever to  call it). Because my plugin is as simple as the Helloworld generated by the SDK. What do you think?

Comment: Got it! I rolled back to the original and started again. Scanned, Autowired and ComponentImport are the answer!  Having those and the default stuff from the template - injection works.